# Delete job posting after a set time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, post

I am trying to develop a web application that allows users to post a short job description and set a time limit as to when the message should cease to show on a time line. (NB: The post is not deleted it only ceases to show up on time lines) The least time is 4hrs other times are in multiples of 4 up to 24hrs. I don't know the best way to approach this,  I am thinking of doing some multi-threading but I am not sure if that is the right approach. In essence I am trying to build something like snapchat but a text based one.

I would to know if:

1. I need a special hosting package to host such an application.
2. If multi threading is a viable option
3. What would you do if you were building an app like this.

NB: I am using ASP.NET with C#

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any threading or special processes, just a better database design.

Also, deleting items from a database generally isn't a good idea, instead just modify your design to be like this:

```
JobPostings( JobPostingId bigint, Title nvarchar, Description nvarchar, VisibleUntil datetime )
```

then just exclude old job postings from your queries:

```
SELECT * FROM JobPostings WHERE VisibleUntil >= NOW()
```

Comment: This is the approach I would use as well. Perhaps with SignalR to make sure the client updates live when lease times expire or become relevant.